# How to find elements that match specific conditions selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i want to crawl data in web, but i don't know how to get data from these tags
[i don't know how to get data from these tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EMLX.png). Please help me

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver.exe")
idx = 0
data = []
title = []


   #print("Process 300 days from {}-{}-{}".format(current_date.day, current_date.month, current_date.year))
url = 'https://24hmoney.vn/stock/HAG/financial-report'
web = browser.get(url)
#Click nut theo quy
btn1 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]")
btn1.click()
#click hien thi tang giam so voi cung ki
#btn2 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/span")

#btn2.click()
lai = browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'p')
for raw in lai:
    data.append(raw.text)
    #print(raw.text)
tieude = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'sticky-col.first-col')

for raw2 in tieude:
    title.append(raw2.text)
    print(raw2.text)
    
#df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["HAG"])
df = pd.DataFrame(title,columns=["Tieude"])
df.to_csv("HAG.csv",index=False)
#a = input()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following code will solve your issue?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://24hmoney.vn/stock/HAG/financial-report'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.select_one('div[class="financial-report-box-content"] table')
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
Tiêu đề Q3/22   % Q3/21 Q2/22   % Q2/21 Q1/22   % Q1/21 Q4/21   % Q4/20 Q3/21   % Q3/20 Q2/21   % Q2/20 Q1/21   % Q1/20 Q4/20   % Q4/19
0   Doanh thu   1441.4  160.1%  1233.6  125.2%  802.6   182.3%  743.7   -19.2%  554.1   -20.9%  547.7   -15.4%  284.4   -66%    920.4   51%
1   Các khoản giảm trừ  NaN NaN 6.2 -81.3%  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.4 68.3%   18.5    -678.5% 6.7 5.7%
2   Doanh thu thuần 1441.4  160.1%  1227.4  125.5%  802.6   201.9%  743.7   -18.6%  554.1   -20.9%  544.3   -14.6%  265.8   -68.1%  913.7   51.6%
3   Giá vốn hàng bán    1160.6  -207.3% 1051.7  -115.3% 512.8   -140.3% 511.5   52.7%   377.6   50.1%   488.4   3%  213.4   61.3%   1082.2  -74.1%
4   Lợi nhuận gộp   280.8   59.1%   175.7   214.4%  289.8   452.8%  232.3   237.9%  176.5   414.3%  55.9    -58.1%  52.4    -81.5%  -168.5  -783.9%
5   Thu nhập tài chính  117.5   -10.9%  95.4    -24.8%  192.4   -44.9%  127.6   -83.7%  131.9   -5.3%   126.8   -34.3%  349.4   122.3%  783.6   203.9%
6   Chi phí tài chính   166.0   76% 875.9   -410.8% 185.9   13.4%   254.7   150.6%  691.5   -161.9% 171.5   -39.8%  214.8   33.6%   503.4   -44.1%
7   Chi phí tiền lãi    166.9   -0.2%   223.6   -35.6%  162.7   18.6%   167.4   66.3%   166.5   21.9%   165.0   25.9%   199.8   25.3%   496.9   -72.7%
8   Lãi/lỗ từ công ty liên doanh    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN -7.6    -1,149% 1.8 -18.8%  4.9 -86.8%
9   Chi phí bán hàng    58.6    -51.5%  90.5    -191.7% 52.1    -202.7% 42.3    34.5%   38.7    47.6%   31.0    76.5%   17.2    79.6%   64.6    14.5%
10  Chi phí quản lý doanh nghiệp    181.1   -60.4%  950.6   322.9%  5.2 101.4%  404.5   56% 457.0   395.4%  224.8   424.4%  367.3   -272.5% 919.8   -890.1%
11  Lãi/lỗ từ hoạt động kinh doanh  354.8   909%    255.2   29.3%   249.3   227.4%  167.7   119.3%  35.2    108.6%  197.3   10,174% -195.7  -202.8% -867.8  -258.5%
12  Thu nhập khác   2.8 35% 24.8    455.4%  5.7 -81.7%  44.0    66.5%   2.1 7.2%    4.5 -85.2%  31.1    68.9%   26.5    140.4%
13  Chi phí khác    -7.4    56.3%   -56.0   66.7%   -15.3   81.7%   -143.8  78.8%   -17.0   89.7%   -168.3  -98.2%  -83.5   -153.3% -679.1  -141.2%
14  Thu nhập khác, ròng -4.6    69.2%   -31.2   81% -9.6    81.7%   -99.8   84.7%   -14.9   90.8%   -163.8  -198.8% -52.4   -260.2% -652.7  -141.2%
15  Lãi/lỗ từ công ty liên doanh    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
16  LỢI NHUẬN TRƯỚC THUẾ    350.2   1,629%  224.0   569.6%  239.8   196.6%  67.9    104.5%  20.2    103.5%  33.5    163.2%  -248.1  -213.3% -1520.5 -196.6%
17  Thuế thu nhập doanh nghiệp – hiện thời  1.2 NaN 1.4 -333.9% 0.2 NaN 0.0 96.6%   NaN NaN 0.3 -76%    NaN NaN 1.1 -27.7%
18  Thuế thu nhập doanh nghiệp – hoãn lại   20.5    1,267%  42.2    -3.9%   18.4    -89.7%  28.6    801.7%  1.5 -19.5%  43.9    1,847%  179.4   15,941% 4.1 -102.4%
19  Chi phí thuế thu nhập doanh nghiệp  19.4    1,191%  40.8    -6.3%   18.2    -89.8%  28.6    656.6%  1.5 -13.8%  43.6    1,718%  179.4   18,238% 5.1 -103%
20  LỢI NHUẬN SAU THUẾ TNDN 369.5   1,599%  264.9   243.7%  258.0   475.2%  96.5    106.3%  21.7    103.8%  77.1    238.6%  -68.8   12.1%   -1525.6 -344.5%
21  Lợi ích của cổ đông thiểu số    8.8 548.1%  -14.9   -3,505% 8.0 177%    -45.7   87% -2.0    99.5%   0.4 100.2%  -10.3   -14.7%  -352.1  11.8%
22  Lợi nhuận của Cổ đông của Công ty mẹ    360.7   1,421%  279.7   265%    250.0   528%    142.2   112.1%  23.7    112.7%  76.6    -56.6%  -58.4   15.6%   -1173.5 -2,193%
23  EPS 4QGN (đ)    389.0   1,396%  301.0   262.6%  270.0   528.6%  153.0   112.1%  26.0    112.9%  83.0    -56.5%  -63.0   16% -1265.0 -540.8%
```

Comment: This it what i need, thank you very much. So, Can you help me, write this table in .csv or .txt ?

Comment: @QuốcViệtĐặng you can save the dataframe to csv with `df.to_csv('my_data.csv')`